# Python: check if a dictionary item is in string, then return the match

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a database table that looks like the following:

```
id    phrases                    message
1     "social media, marketing"  "This person is in marketing!"
2     "finance, fintech          "This person is in finance!"
```

I've looped through the key phrases and added them to a dictionary, like so:

```
messages = self.db_access.execute("SELECT * FROM messages")
messages = self.db_access.fetchall()
print(len(messages))
if self.db_access.rowcount > 0:
    has_message = True
    phrase_list = {}
    for the_rule in messages:
        print(the_rule[1])
        rule = the_rule[1].split(',')
        for phrase in rule:
            phrase = str(phrase)
            phrase_list[phrase] = str(the_rule[2])
    print(phrase_list)
    print("\n")
else:
    has_message = False
```

This then produces the following:

```
# phrase_list
{'social media': 'This person is in marketing!', 
 'marketing': 'This person is in marketing!', 
 'finance': 'This person is in finance!', 
 'fintech': 'This person is in finance!'}
```

So, each phrase has it's own accompanying message, which is used elsewhere.

Now, I can compare those dict keys against a string, like so:

```
descriptions = ["I am in marketing, and it is super awesome", "I am in finance, and it is super awesome"]
```

My next step is to compare that string with the keys, and if it contains any of the keywords, then print the matching key and its value/message. This is what I have so far:

```
for description in descriptions:
    print(description)
    if has_message == True:
        if any(x in description for x in phrase_list):
            # print matching keyword and message
        else:
            print("No matches, but a phrase list exists")
```

So my question is, what do I need to replace that comment with to output 1) the keyword it matched with, and 2) the message associated with that keyword?

Comment: So what you want is to see if the strings from the `descriptions` list contain any string stored as a value on the dict?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Not quite. The OP wants to test each string in the `descriptions` list to see if it contain any string stored as a _key_ in `phrase_list`, and if so, print the key & its associated value. This would be easy if all the keys were single words, but keys like 'social media' make it a little bit tricky.

Comment: @PM2Ring - Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to restructure your code a bit. The need for that arouses from the use of `any` which does not return information on which `x` made the expression evaluate as `True`. It just tells you that **someone** did or that **noone** did. If you do care about which one you have to loop through or possibly use `next`. Anyway, here is one way to do it:

```
for description in descriptions:
    print(description)
    if has_message == True:
        for x in phrase_list:
            if x in description:
                print(x, phrase_list[x])
                break
        else:
            print("No matches, but a phrase list exists")
```

---

Note:

if the `else` on the `for` is confusing, just remove it. The code will reach it only if the x is not in any description anyway.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you. It fits perfectly with my existing code, and doesn't require more functions or imported libraries!

Answer (score 1):

Might want to tweak it a bit, but you can use a regular expression to search for a matching key, then look that back up in your dictionary, eg:

```
import re

phrase_list = {'social media': 'This person is in marketing!', 
 'marketing': 'This person is in marketing!', 
 'finance': 'This person is in finance!', 
 'fintech': 'This person is in finance!'}

descriptions = ["I am in marketing, and it is super awesome", "I am in finance, and it is super awesome", 'john smith']

def find_department(lookup, text):
    m = re.search('|'.join(sorted(lookup, key=len, reverse=True)), text)
    if m:
        return lookup[m.group(0)]
    else:
        return 'This person is a mystery!'
```

Then running this gives you:

```
for desc in descriptions:
    print(desc, '->', find_department(phrase_list, desc))

#I am in marketing, and it is super awesome -> This person is in marketing!
#I am in finance, and it is super awesome -> This person is in finance!
#john smith -> This person is a mystery!
```